# How can I extract records from a file if they include a specific set of strings?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, sed, awk

I am analyzing a file `xyz.txt` which contains hifen separated records. I want to extract records based on the presence of the strings `FADED:100`,  `AM:FF` and `GG`. Subsequently, I need to write them to a new file, `faded100.txt`. The source file include more then 40 thousand records, looking like below.

```
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    rtuyss  A/A go go go go go go go go go go go go go go  IRE AP  QQ Z
ORDER xxxxxxx1

country: 201  NVDS        TEMPROR   EXTREME

BUS TIME:       TRASS: 12       AIDED: 12        FADED: 100

                      U  U  U  u  U  A  U  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                 GG   Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  O  Y  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   POU
ATM UNITED #  AM:FF   Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  O  Y  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   POU POU POU POU
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

rtuyss  A/A go go go go go go go go go go go go go go  IRE AP  QQ Z
ORDER xxxxxxx1

country: 201  NVDS        TEMPROR   EXTREME

BUS TIME:       TRASS: 12       AIDED: 12        FADED: 200

                      U  U  U  u  U  A  U  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  ZZ  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  O  Y  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   POU
ATM UNITED #   AM:FF  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  O  Y  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   POU POU POU POU

--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

rtuyss  A/A go go go go go go go go go go go go go go  IRE AP  QQ Z
ORDER xxxxxxx1

country: 201  NVDS        TEMPROR   EXTREME

BUS TIME:       TRASS: 12       AIDED: 12        FADED: 100

                     U  U  U  u  U  A  U  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  IP Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  O  Y  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   POU
ATM UNITED #   AM:FF Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  O  Y  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   POU POU POU POU

--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --
```

Comment: Looks very doable, but could you paste the above as text?  I found `FADED:100`,  `AM:FF`, but where is `GG`?

Comment: It is above AM:FF character like upper row of that.

Comment: Done Jacob i pasted it.

Comment: Wait, one more question: you say `AM:FF` *above* `GG`, but in the first record, `GG` is *below* `AM:FF`. That's the one to keep, right?

Comment: Yes jacob we need to keep those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54171/discussion-between-shekhar-and-jacob-vlijm).

Comment: Jacob which python shows I don't have python ,Perl I have version 5.005_03 built for PA-risc2.0.

Comment: Hi @shekar, you really should have mentioned you are not using Ubuntu. This is waisting people's time. Asking here is expecting answers to work on Ubuntu, which the answer does.

Comment: I apologize , I am fixing this now moved to Unix stackchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Extracting records from a text file if a set of strings can be found in the record

The script below will extract records from your file, if they meet the conditions you described in your question.
If the ***order*** is important, please see my notes in *If the order is important*.

Since the script reads the file per line, and subsequently processes the lines *per record*, it should be pretty fast on big files.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

#--- set the strings to be (needed to be) found below
checks = ["FADED: 100", "AM:FF", "GG"]
#---

f = sys.argv[1]; out = sys.argv[2]; rec = []; test = []

with open(f) as src, open(out, "a+") as targ:
    for l in src:
        rec.append(l)
        if l.startswith("---"):
            if len(test) == 3:
                for l in rec:
                    targ.write(l)
            rec = []; test = []
        else:           
            for s in checks:
                if s in l:
                    test.append(checks.index(s))
                    break
```

#### What the script does exactly

- The script reads a record (loading per line), keeps at the same time record if any of the strings `["FADED: 100", "AM:FF", "GG"]` occurs in the line.
- If not all three strings occur in the record, the record is deleted from "cache", the next record is loaded and so on

#### If the order is important

If it is important in which *order* (lines containing-) the strings appear inside your record, you can replace the line:

```
if len(test) == 3:
```

by:

```
if test == [0, 2, 1]
```

where the numbers refer to the *indices* of the strings in the list `checks = ["FADED: 100", "AM:FF", "GG"]` (where 0 is the first string)

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `filter_records.py`
2. Run the script with the source (file with your current records) and the output file as arguments, e.g.:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/filter_records.py /path/to/inputfile.txt /path/to/outputfile.txt
   ```

#### The result (on your small example)

```
    rtuyss  A/A go go go go go go go go go go go go go go  IRE AP  QQ Z
ORDER xxxxxxx1

country: 201  NVDS        TEMPROR   EXTREME

BUS TIME:       TRASS: 12       AIDED: 12        FADED: 100

                      U  U  U  u  U  A  U  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                 GG   Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  O  Y  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   POU
ATM UNITED #  AM:FF   Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  O  Y  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   POU POU POU POU
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --
```

Comment: Hey Jacob +1, I got the desired output followed your script...cheers