# Display entire chunk of data A---B if complex filters matches

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Possibly stated as duplicate..thanks for accepting

```
ORDER ALPHA

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ90rty   K/K AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     A/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y
ORDER BURY

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ903901  A/A AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     A/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y

ORDER ALUIO

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       PAT: NA        NOUN: AP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ903901  U/U AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     Y/Y WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y
ORDER AL123  ...cont....
```

Display or delete or redirect entire ORDER to ORDER last line data before new order starts, if these filters satisfies, condition 1:IF NOUN  :XP and A/A above A/A is present delete that order or parse to another file. Condition 2:IF NOUN  :AP and Y/Y above U/U is there  delete that order or parse to another file.Deleted Output looks like

```
ORDER ALPHA
Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ90rty   K/K AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     A/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y
```

Like this many conditions are there i will add conditions on my own but these are some conditions i posted.....
NOTE:Rows are dynamic and ORDER **** (***)may be any letter,but ORDER is constant.

Comment: What's the difference between this and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348042/70524?

Comment: Homework? Not very good to ask others to do it for you.

Comment: Ya I know not homework but an issue no where related to my work, I would opted manually found Linux has powers to do this to perform an immediate task I cannot start investing time sed or awk it requires lot of time to Pioneer ...hope you understand

Comment: At muru there is difference it was wrt key if I remove key and perform I am unable to display records so actually dispoed my production log

Comment: Hi shekar, just change the conditions and you have an exact copy of this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/886825/how-can-i-extract-records-from-a-file-if-they-include-a-specific-set-of-strings/886901#886901 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by dividing and conquering the text. The Python script below does exactly that - it reads the file line by line, collecting all lines related to an order, and then passes that information to the function that parses each order to determine whether or not it should be printed. While slightly verbose, it works fairly decently, although it is effectively a two nested loops which probably will give *O(n^2)* performance.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
def parse_order(order,order_lines):
    flag1 = False
    flag2 = False
    xp_counter = 0
    ap_counter = 0
    for line in order_lines:
        if 'Wrong Trace:' in line:
            words = line.split()
            if 'NOUN:' in words[-2] and 'XP' in words[-1]:
                flag1 = True
                continue
            if 'NOUN:' in words[-2] and 'AP' in words[-1]:
                flag2 = True
                continue
        if flag1 and 'A/A' in line: xp_counter += 1
        if flag2 and ( 'Y/Y' in line or 'U/U' in line):  
            ap_counter += 1
    if xp_counter == 2 or ap_counter == 2:
        return
    print("".join([order]+order_lines)) 

def main():
    buffer=[]
    last_order = None
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if line.startswith('ORDER'):
               current_order = line
               if not last_order:
                   last_order = current_order
                   continue
               parse_order(last_order,buffer)
               last_order = current_order
               buffer = []
               continue
            buffer.append(line)
        parse_order(last_order,buffer) 

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

The script has been tested with slightly modified input file from OP. As you can see below, the `BURY` and `ALUIO` are skipped:

```
$ ./parse_orders.py input.txt                                                             
ORDER ALPHA

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ90rty   K/K AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     A/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y

ORDER GAMMA

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ90rty   K/K AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     A/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y
```

Comment: the script is printing some negative results for for condition like if NOUN :XP for X/X and Y/Y it dhould print only NOUN: XP relatd things but it is printing NOUN :AP results also we need to delete this from current file i have backup.

Comment: Serg let us assume there is only condition is required not required NOUN :AP, it has to delete only for this condition (If NOUN :XP where A/A above K/K is present delete that record from file).I will harcode each time and run script for multiple conditions thats OK i guess.